# Can I use a gas range on unsealed subflooring?

Tags: wood, natural-gas

Vinyl flooring was installed under front half of depth, but not back half. Older house has some leveling issues so we repaired the best we could. Small dip under stove prevents vinyl from adhering. Original subfloor has poured leveler, is sealed and primed, a layer of lauan, then LVT. So we’re talking about 12”x30” area under back half of range being over top bare lauan. New LG gas range. Fire hazard?

Comment: Luan doesn’t seem any more flammable than sheet vinyl flooring. One set of LG’s instructions say to not install over carpet, and ensure the flooring can handle 180 degrees Fahrenheit.

Comment: Protip: Luan plywood is not suitable as a vinyl flooring underlayment. It will void most flooring product warranties. It's soft, may contain voids, and may contain salts that will stain the floor.

Comment: Only thing with it being unsealed is that spills will soak in easier.

Comment: Also have a layer of roll underlayment on top of the lauan. Just not on the unsealed section. Floor is compliant with installation guidelines.

Comment: Good point about the spills. I am a heavy duty canning guru. I think I’ll pull the range and finish the section simply for that reason. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No modern kitchen range is going to have material requirements for the floor. You can put it on a stack of newspaper if you like. Such ovens are used daily in millions of rustic cabins with tinder-dry pine floors, for example, and most ovens have highly flammable dust bunnies the size of, well... *bunnies* under them. If there were heat and sparks down there we'd all be doomed.

When in doubt, read the manual that came with your new range.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true. "No modern kitchen range is going to have material requirements for the floor."

Absolutely read your manual. For example my 2023 LG states flooring should be able to resist 167F degrees.